# How to get Label inner text from Codebehind

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I have html label contol without runat="server"

Does it possible to get inner text from code behind c#?

Label:

```
<label id="lblClanName">Text Here</label>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every time an ASP.Net page is posted back to the server it is recreated from scratch using the custom code contained in the page (such as calls to a database), the HTTP post/get collections (which include `ViewState`), any custom data in `Application`, `Cache`, `Session`, static objects, etc.

If the value does not exist in any of those locations, the server doesn't have access to it. A common trick to pass data from the client is to simply use a hidden field. If you want something more elegant, you can use asynchronous AJAX to send/receive data from the server.

Or in this case, you could just add `runat="server"` to an `asp:Label`. `ViewState` will maintain the value between postbacks, though it will **not** reflect changes made client-side unless (once again) the data is somehow passed back to the server.

Note that `ViewState` is typically a bad thing because it essentially doubles the size of your data (or more) and (in my opinion) encourages sloppy design.

Answer (score 2):

i don't think you can do it.either you can use js get the lable,and call js method from code behind

Answer (score 2):

Short answer:  no.

To access this from your code-behind, you will minimally need to add `runat="server"` to your `label`.  This will allow you to access it using [Page.FindControl(String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31hxzsdw.aspx).

The preferred approach, if you are able to modify the front-end code, would be to use an [<asp:Label />](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.label%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).  This will allow you easy access by just using the control's ID in the code-behind, specifically its `Text` property.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to know how to parse a string value for the inner html, or do you expect your web page do have text written to the label at runtime?

```
string labelHtml = "<label id="lblClanName">Text Here</label>";
   XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
   doc.LoadXml(labelHtml);
   string innerText = doc.DocumentElement.InnerText;
```

Why do you need the text between a label, is this for a live web page? This sound like a bad design more than a requirement.